# sed: removing dublicated patterns in the log file

Tags: sed, cat

I am working with post-processing of the log file arranged in the following format:

```
Finding intramodel H-bonds
Constraints relaxed by 0.55 angstroms and 20 degrees
Models used:
    1.1 SarsCov2_structure31R_nsp5holo_rep1.pdb
    1.6 SarsCov2_structure31R_nsp5holo_rep1.pdb
    1.10 SarsCov2_structure31R_nsp5holo_rep1.pdb
    1.8 SarsCov2_structure31R_nsp5holo_rep1.pdb
    1.2 SarsCov2_structure31R_nsp5holo_rep1.pdb
    1.3 SarsCov2_structure31R_nsp5holo_rep1.pdb
    1.4 SarsCov2_structure31R_nsp5holo_rep1.pdb
    1.7 SarsCov2_structure31R_nsp5holo_rep1.pdb
    1.5 SarsCov2_structure31R_nsp5holo_rep1.pdb
    1.9 SarsCov2_structure31R_nsp5holo_rep1.pdb

6 H-bonds
H-bonds (donor, acceptor, hydrogen, D..A dist, D-H..A dist):
SarsCov2_structure31R_nsp5holo_rep1.pdb #1.3/? ASN 142 ND2   SarsCov2_structure31R_nsp5holo_rep1.pdb #1.3/A UNL 1 N   SarsCov2_structure31R_nsp5holo_rep1.pdb #1.3/? ASN 142 2HD2   3.419  2.541
SarsCov2_structure31R_nsp5holo_rep1.pdb #1.5/? GLN 189 NE2   SarsCov2_structure31R_nsp5holo_rep1.pdb #1.5/A UNL 1 O   SarsCov2_structure31R_nsp5holo_rep1.pdb #1.5/? GLN 189 1HE2   2.883  2.159
SarsCov2_structure31R_nsp5holo_rep1.pdb #1.6/? HIS 163 NE2   SarsCov2_structure31R_nsp5holo_rep1.pdb #1.6/A UNL 1 O   no hydrogen
```

From this log I need to take all the lines after the 3rd line, and then delete all dublicated patterns "SarsCov2_structure31R_nsp5holo_rep1.pdb". May I use some regex with sed to detect any phrase matching such patter in the log ( which ends with *.pdb) that should be removed automatically for each processed log?
So the expected output should be:

```
Models used:
    1.1 
    1.6 
    1.10 
    1.8 
    1.2 
    1.3 
    1.4 
    1.7 
    1.5 
    1.9 

6 H-bonds
H-bonds (donor, acceptor, hydrogen, D..A dist, D-H..A dist):
 #1.3/? ASN 142 ND2    #1.3/A UNL 1 N    #1.3/? ASN 142 2HD2   3.419  2.541
 #1.5/? GLN 189 NE2    #1.5/A UNL 1 O    #1.5/? GLN 189 1HE2   2.883  2.159
 #1.6/? HIS 163 NE2    #1.6/A UNL 1 O   no hydrogen            3.299  N/A
 #1.7/? GLN 189 NE2    #1.7/A UNL 1 O    #1.7/? GLN 189 1HE2   3.109  2.147
 #1.9/? ASN 142 ND2    #1.9/A UNL 1 O    #1.9/? ASN 142 1HD2   3.032  2.319
 #1.10/? GLN 189 NE2   #1.10/A UNL 1 O   #1.10/? GLN 189 1HE2  3.054  2.125
```

Here is some example without regex, which does not work yet :-)

```
cat test.log | tail -n +2 | sed -e "/SarsCov2_structure31R_nsp5holo_rep1.pdb/d" >> ./test2.log
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using `sed`

```
$ sed 's/[[:alnum:]_]*\.pdb//g;1,2d' input_file
Models used:
    1.1
    1.6
    1.10
    1.8
    1.2
    1.3
    1.4
    1.7
    1.5
    1.9

6 H-bonds
H-bonds (donor, acceptor, hydrogen, D..A dist, D-H..A dist):
 #1.3/? ASN 142 ND2    #1.3/A UNL 1 N    #1.3/? ASN 142 2HD2   3.419  2.541
 #1.5/? GLN 189 NE2    #1.5/A UNL 1 O    #1.5/? GLN 189 1HE2   2.883  2.159
 #1.6/? HIS 163 NE2    #1.6/A UNL 1 O   no hydrogen
```

Comment: Thank you very much!   I tried to pipe your sollution to "cat", for the case of the dealing with multiple log files (to deleate patterns in each logs and fuse all results together. It looks like cat $log |  sed -e 's/[[:alnum:]_]*\.pdb//g;1,2d'. would it be ok like this?

Comment: @MaîtreRenard A better approach may be `sed -e 's/[[:alnum:]_]*\.pdb//g;1,2d' <<< "$log"`

Comment: what is the difference? in fact I piped it to CAT in order to preserve the structure of the log in the combined file (this is executed into for loop in bash script which takes each $log and remove the patterns from each file and then fuse all logs together). Without CAT the combined log has not the structure corresponded to each initial log fille, so ..

Comment: You should not lose the structure. I have tested and the structure is retained within the variable. The difference is rather than two commands, you do it with one. In regards to the question asked, the command provided should suffice. If you have another question please open a new question for it.

Answer (score 2):

You may use this `sed`:

```sh
sed -E '1,2d; s/[[:blank:]]*[^[:blank:]]+\.pdb//g' file

Models used:
    1.1
    1.6
    1.10
    1.8
    1.2
    1.3
    1.4
    1.7
    1.5
    1.9

6 H-bonds
H-bonds (donor, acceptor, hydrogen, D..A dist, D-H..A dist):
 #1.3/? ASN 142 ND2 #1.3/A UNL 1 N #1.3/? ASN 142 2HD2   3.419  2.541
 #1.5/? GLN 189 NE2 #1.5/A UNL 1 O #1.5/? GLN 189 1HE2   2.883  2.159
 #1.6/? HIS 163 NE2 #1.6/A UNL 1 O   no hydrogen
```

**Details:**

- `1,2d`: Removes first 2 lines
- `s/[[:blank:]]*[^[:blank:]]+\.pdb//g`: Removes 0 or more spaces filled by 1+ of non space characters followed by  .adb from each line globally

Comment: thnak you!! in fact the phrase (which should be eliminated) might be different in different logs, but it always end with .pdb". May I use another regex in sed to remove any phrase ending with *.pdb in the log ?

Comment: Ok check my updated answer

Answer (score 1):

With your shown samples please try following `awk` code. Simple explanation would be, firstly checking condition if `FNR>2` then only run all other commands(inside condition block). Inside condition using `gsub` to Globally substitute `[[:space:]]*SarsCov2_structure31R_nsp5holo_rep1\.pdb` with NULL as per shown samples and printing the current line.

```
awk '
FNR>2{
  gsub(/[[:space:]]*SarsCov2_structure31R_nsp5holo_rep1\.pdb/,"")
print
}
' Input_file
```